# Python 2.7.9 on Centos 6.7?

Tags: python, linux, centos

I need to upgrade Python on my centos 6.7 machine to 2.7.9, but everything I've been reading has said that will break "yum" on my system. Does this issue still exist? I'm only finding much older posts confirming, and I don't really know what I'm doing so I don't want to break anything.

Comment: "Need" for a project or "need" because the operating system is suggesting it?

Answer (score 4):

You can install additional version of Python:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.9.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.9
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make
make altinstall
```

Finally check the Python version:

```
python2.7 -V
```

should return

```
Python 2.7.9
```

The old version of Python should be available as python2:

```
python2 -V
```

(Python 2.7.5 in my case)

**Important:** You may need to install the prerequisites before compiling Python:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install sqlite-devel
```

I hope that this will solve your problem!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Helped

Comment: I install updated python from source by hand.
 After `make` operation, an executable `python` is generated in the source folder. But the edition is same with original existed one in the system(CentOS7.1x86_64),
 which is really wired. And I don't have any clue.
 Anyway, this script works for me. [python2.7.9_centos_installation.sh](https://gist.github.com/guy4261/0e9f4081f1c6b078b436). Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have had some trouble using Python on CentOS due to yum requring Python2.6.  But you should be able to upgrade and run yum.  `yum` is python script and if it doesn't work maybe you can run it with the right Python version. For example

```
python2.7 /usr/bin/yum .....
```